# Plugin function throwing error for missing argument

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm trying to extend a plugin to allow for a limit to be added to the database call but it's throwing an error:

> Missing argument 1 for Craft\Curate_UsersContentService::getRank(),
>   called

The services file has a function in it called `getRank()` and I've added a `$count` variable to it `getRank($count)`. My twig template then calls it with the following code:

```
{% set count = 10 %}
{% set rank = craft.curate.getRank(count) %}
```

But the above error is thrown. What an I missing?

Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so worked this out whilst working on another plugin. I had to add a variable to the CurateVariable file in order for the template to be able to use the function. Problem solved.